# Physical meaning of the convection term in the momentum equation of acoustic wave

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, vector-fields, flow

In deriving the acoustic wave equation, the momentum equation is used.

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}+
(\mathbf{u}\nabla)\mathbf{u}=-\frac{1}{\rho} \nabla p$$

Intuitively, the convection term $(\mathbf{u}\nabla)\mathbf{u} $ represents a component of acceleration, but how is this acceleration originate?

P.S.
What is the difference between $(\mathbf{u}\nabla)\mathbf{u} $ and  $(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u} $?

Comment: They presumably mean the same thing, but the former is extremely confusing while the latter is perfectly clear.

Comment: Acoustic wave is linear, you should not need this term at all (unless there is some background flow velocity u$_0$).

Comment: @G.Smith Is $(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u}=(\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z})\mathbf{u}?

Comment: You left out the final $ so the MathJax didn’t display as math.

Comment: $$(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u}=\left(u_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+u_y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+u_z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)\mathbf{u}$$ This is very different from what you had. The $\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla$ is a scalar differential *operator*, and is not the divergence $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: @G.Smith Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The momentum equation written above is written for an incompressible fluid, otherwise the density $\rho$ would have to be written inside the partial derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial\rho\mathbf{u}}{\partial t}
$$

Hence, the momentum in a Control Volume can change by either:

- a change in velocity of the fluid
- convection (transport) of momentum through the CV boundaries. This is the meaning of the term $(\mathbf{u}\nabla)\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: While reading your answer again, I got another question: how to derive the convective term $(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u}$ from the change of momentum $\frac{\partial\rho\mathbf{u}}{\partial t}$? It seems to me that $\frac{\partial\rho\mathbf{u}}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\mathbf{u}+\rho\frac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial t}$? But how to proceed?